# How to make an AWS static website visible to my firm only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, auth0, vpc

I have successfully hosted a webpage on an amazon s3 bucket. How can i make it internal to my company alone? Is VPC what I should be looking for? Is it possible to add Auth0 on top of this ? The webpage is simple HTML, CSS, Javascript and Jquery. Nothing fancy

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by "to my company alone"? Does your company have a Direct Connect connection to AWS? Does your company access the Internet via a single gateway, therefore always appearing to come from the same IP address? Would you want it visible to anyone coming from your company, or only to specific people within the company? Any more details you can provide would be helpful!

Comment: Well, i want it to be visible to anyone from my company. I have no clue about the company network infrastructure. Any routines i can run to find out? Or maybe i should be simply asking my network administrator? Sorry for being this unclear. I didn't mean to equivocate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html

> Private IPv4 Addresses and Internal DNS Hostnames
>
> A private IPv4 address is an IP address that's not reachable over the
>   Internet. You can use private IPv4 addresses for communication between
>   instances in the same network (EC2-Classic or a VPC). For more
>   information about the standards and specifications of private IPv4
>   addresses, see RFC 1918.
>
> Note You can create a VPC with a publicly routable CIDR block that
>   falls outside of the private IPv4 address ranges specified in RFC
>   1918. However, for the purposes of this documentation, we refer to private IPv4 addresses (or 'private IP addresses') as the IP addresses
>   that are within the IPv4 CIDR range of your VPC. When you launch an
>   instance, we allocate a private IPv4 address for the instance using
>   DHCP. Each instance is also given an internal DNS hostname that
>   resolves to the private IPv4 address of the instance; for example,
>   ip-10-251-50-12.ec2.internal. You can use the internal DNS hostname
>   for communication between instances in the same network, but we can't
>   resolve the DNS hostname outside the network that the instance is in.
>
> An instance launched in a VPC is given a primary private IP address in
>   the IPv4 address range of the subnet. For more information, see Subnet
>   Sizing in the Amazon VPC User Guide. If you don't specify a primary
>   private IP address when you launch the instance, we select an
>   available IP address in the subnet's IPv4 range for you. Each instance
>   in a VPC has a default network interface (eth0) that is assigned the
>   primary private IPv4 address. You can also specify additional private
>   IPv4 addresses, known as secondary private IPv4 addresses. Unlike
>   primary private IP addresses, secondary private IP addresses can be
>   reassigned from one instance to another. For more information, see
>   Multiple IP Addresses.
>
> For instances launched in EC2-Classic, we release the private IPv4
>   address when the instance is stopped or terminated. If you restart
>   your stopped instance, it receives a new private IPv4 address.
>
> For instances launched in a VPC, a private IPv4 address remains
>   associated with the network interface when the instance is stopped and
>   restarted, and is released when the instance is terminated.
>
> If you create a custom firewall configuration in EC2-Classic, you must
>   create a rule in your firewall that allows inbound traffic from port
>   53 (DNS)—with a destination port from the ephemeral range—from the
>   address of the Amazon DNS server; otherwise, internal DNS resolution
>   from your instances fails. If your firewall doesn't automatically
>   allow DNS query responses, then you need to allow traffic from the IP
>   address of the Amazon DNS server. To get the IP address of the Amazon
>   DNS server, use the following command from within your instance:

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a definition of "to my company".

For example:

- It could be that the website is accessible to the entire world, but requires a password (known to people in your company)
- It could be that the website is only accessible to the IP address that your company uses to access the Internet
- It could be that you create a network connection between AWS and your company network so that it is only accessible from your company network (just like an internal application)

The configuration to use ill depend upon how you want to serve and protect the application. For example, Security Groups can restrict access to a limited range of IP addresses. Definitely have a chat with your network administrator to figure out how you'd like to proceed.